# Build Project with Websphere JVM

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, websphere

How to do you compile a certain project using Websphere JVM with ant? I know ant requires a JDK but there must be a way outside of RAD/Eclipse to compile a project against Websphere supplied JVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your classpath to the WebSphere JDK (sub)directory and add the WebSphere JDK to your PATH environment variable. You should find the JVM in your WebSphere folders.

Comment: Hi Udo, So my RAD JDK is at: C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\jdk Where as the JRE my Websphere is insalled at C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre. Confusion is RAD JDK has its own JRE folder and so does the Websphere (as shown above)

Comment: The RAD ships with serveral jdks for different server versions. C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\jdk should be the RAD jdk while C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre is the runtime for a was 7. Depending on your installation you may have a C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v6\java\jre or 6.1 as well. I'd go for the SDP\jdk.